# NancyFX Doesn't Recognize Custom Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, nancy

I am using NancyFX for my API Gateway and I have a model such as the following:

```
public class CreatePerson
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string Phone {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [MyCustomValidationRule]
    public string ImagePath {get;set;}
}
```

It uses both a custom `MyCustomValidationRule` attribute as well as the provided `Phone` and `Required` attributes.

In my module I have the following:

```
public class PersonModule
{
  public PersonModule()
  {
      Post["/",true] = async (context,cancel)=> 
      {
          var request = this.BindAndValidate<CreatePerson>();

          if(!ModelValidationResult.IsValid)
          {
              //THIS NEVER HITS
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The `[Required]` attributes are working and if I omit any of the properties, it works fine. However, if I pass in an invalid phone (such as `sdfsdgsdg` or I do something that clearly breaks `MyCustomValidationRule` attribute, it is not caught. Furthermore, I have placed a breakpoint in the constructor of the `MyCustomValidationRule` attribute, and it never hits.

Why is this not hitting?

Answer (score 2):

@TheJediCowboy. I had the same problem in my project.

I can't check my theory now, but I think you should add ValidationAdapter for each kind of attribute, example you can find on [github](https://github.com/xt0rted/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations.Extensions/tree/master/src/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations.Extensions)
I think only 4 validation attribute will work in default package(Range, Regex, Required, StringLength), please check list of validation adapters [github](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Validation.DataAnnotations)
For custom attributes required add custom adapter, I think.

**UPDATED**
This solution checked and works good.
For validation attribute (except Range, Regex, Required and StringLength) required add validation adapter (or override exiting). Nancy use all validation adapters that are in the project.